# Интеграция YouTube видео на сайт

Tags: javascript, html, css, youtube, youtube-api

Подскажите, как реализовать такой preload.

[image: img]

**ТЗ:** Модуль видео - проигрывание видео из Youtube в popup окне.

Видео я интегрировал через iframe, как это предлагает YouTube, но API не позволяет мне реализовать внешний вид, так как на макете.

[Демонстрация YouTube Player API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo?hl=ru)

Я решил сделать ссылку, и во внутрь поместить изображение. При клике на изображение вывести popup окно с видео, но есть проблемы:

**1:** При клике на изображение, вылазит popup-окно с видео, но как при этом инициировать его воспроизведение я не знаю.

**2:** При закрытии popup-окна, мне надо поставить на паузу или сбросить воспроизведение с начала видео.

**Пример:**

https://jsfiddle.net/Devinora/n2mgerac/

```js
let link = document.getElementsByClassName("preload-link")[0];
let popUp = document.getElementsByClassName("pop-up-w")[0];
let close = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
let popUpActiveName = "pop-up-w_active";

link.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 popUp.classList.add(popUpActiveName);
});

popUp.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 if(this === e.target) {
  popUp.classList.remove(popUpActiveName);
 } else if (e.target === close) {
  popUp.classList.remove(popUpActiveName);
 }
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100%;
  background: #000;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 vertical-align: middle;
 border: none;
}

.preload-link {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.preload-link:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 0;
 height: 0;
 border-top: 25px solid transparent;
 border-left: 50px solid red;
 border-bottom: 25px solid transparent;
}

.preload-link:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 4px solid red;
  border-radius: 100%;
}

.pop-up-w {
  position: fixed;
  display: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0, .5);
}

.pop-up-w_active {
  display: flex;
}

.video {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
}

.close {
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="video-w">
  <a href="#" class="preload-link">
    <img src="https://www.hollywoodreporter.com/sites/default/files/2012/12/img_logo_blue.jpg" alt="Preload" class="preload-img">
  </a>
  <div class="pop-up-w">
    <iframe class="video" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xUV_Sm63ByA" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    <span class="close">X</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**P.S:** Если необходимо, я сделаю пример кода.

Comment: Здравствуйте. Базовая вещь, основа основ для верстальщика. 1). Вам нужно определиться с модальными окнами, что вы будете использовать. Сейчас у вас не модальное окно, а нечто непонятное. Это непонятное скорее больше доставит проблем, чем сама реализация видео. Возьмите модальные окна от bootstrap-4 или ещё какие-нибудь. Когда определитесь с окнами, то можно будет реализовывать видео.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov, а что не так с мои модульным окном? Единственное чего я в нем не сделал, так это не поставил overflow: hidden для body, что бы не было прокрутки страницы. И это просто для примера, что бы было более понятно что мне необходимо. Раз вы лучше знаете как сделать модульное окно (правильно), то с чем собственно нужно определиться?